# sstatic.net blacklisted for bad reputation: What can I do?

Tags: support, cdn

We are behind a Websense proxy at work and since this weekend the `sstatic.net` domain doesn't answer anymore. This has some unpleasant side effects. For example the loading of a Stack Overflow page being frozen until the browser times out requests to `sstatic.net` CSS and JavaScript. Page loads can take up to 5 minutes during the day.

Since I'm currently in the middle of playing with some tech I was learning with the help of Stack Overflow, this is quite annoying. After nagging our security director he told me that the site had been blacklisted for mobile badware related bad reputation (EDIT: **source** DVLabs/Exploit Type : Mobile - for Europe)

Apparently this already happened in the past; I wanted to give a heads up in case some action is needed by SE staff. I  also wanted to know whether I could run around this problem, for example by using a different and "clean" IP through my hosts file? Alternatively are there proxies for the sstatic.net domain?

Comment: *mumble* *mumble* incompetent security vendors *mumble* *mumble*.

Comment: I guess you meant `websense.com`. I think you should report this to them and insist that they whitelist `sstatic.net`. Also, you should ask them to explain why they think the domain should be blacklisted.

Comment: @Krumia I added what little info I received regarding the blocking reason

Comment: This is happening again... :( Blocked as 'Content Delivery Networks'. Why the heck would that even be a blocked category?

Comment: @neminem Yeah, I saw the problem reappear... I'm chalking it up now to a desire to feel the illusion of security rather true security, and am not really looking for a way to correct it anymore